# using local in racket

Tags: scheme, local, racket

```
(define (flip l)
  (local [(define (flip p)
            (make-posn (posn-y p)
                       (posn-x p)))]))
```

this just flips the positions of two posns. It should be working. Am I doing something wrong with the parenthesis?

Keeps giving me this error- local: expected an expression after the local definitions, but nothing's there.

Comment: Are you trying to define a function? If so, why are you trying to use `local`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`local`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/local.html) special form expects a body after the definition, so basically you're missing the call to `flip`:

```
(define (flip l)
  (local [(define (flip p)
            (make-posn (posn-y p)
                       (posn-x p)))]
    (flip l)))
```

... But using `local` here is completely unnecessary! you can achieve the same effect directly:

```
(define (flip p)
  (make-posn (posn-y p)
             (posn-x p)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [documentation for `local`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/local.html), you'll see that it expects a *body* after the definitions. You don't have anything after your closing `]`, so it's complaining that the body is missing from `local`.

I can't really tell what you're trying to do here, but maybe understanding the cause of the error will help get you going in the right direction.